# Returning DISTINCT rows in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. One is clients, that has a clientID and entity, the other is LogOnLink which has a clientID and LogonID. The LogOnLink table can the same clientID entered into it multiple times. So i'm trying to run a query where I do a search for an Entity Joining the LogonLink table. The problem i'm having is that if an entity is in the logonLink table 20 times, i get the name returned twenty times. How do i make it so that it only shows me one instance of an entity. Keep in mind that there can be similar entity names so If i have "Company 1" and "Company 2" in the db, i need to show both companies if someone types in companies. I tried doing DISTINCT but it doesn't distinct it by clientID in the LogOnLink table. Here's what i have so far.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ll.logonID, entity 
FROM clients c 
INNER JOIN LogOnsLink ll ON ll.clientID = c.clientID 
WHERE c.entity LIKE '%Com%' 
ORDER BY entity

Clients Table
------------------------------------
clientID    entity
2             Company A
8             Company B
43            Company C

LogOnLinks Table
------------------------------------
LogonLinkID    clientID    LogonID
4                  2           3
5                  2           7
21                 8           20
6                  2           9
3                  8           10
45                 43          3
```

Comment: Could you add sample data to your question along with desired output? Often sample data is better than a long paragraph description.

Comment: DISTINCT removes duplicates based on the data you're selecting.  If you want distinct by clientId, then you need to include that in your select.  And then you probably want to remove one of the columns you're selecting that's causing the duplicates rows (different data).

Comment: I updated the question with data. Also @Ashley, the columns selected are needed. I added ll.clientID but that still returns the same results.

Comment: What do you want to return?  Based on your sample data you'd expect multiple rows per `entity`, because the same company can have multiple `LogonID`.

Comment: really just want to return the logOnID and from there i'll use it to run another query

Comment: Then just select the logOnID. DISTINCT is only going to remove rows of duplicate data. The more columns you add to the select, the more rows you're going to have in your output with different data in those columns. –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to perform some kind of aggregate on the data from LogOnsLink or you'll always get 20 rows...

Try this

```
SELECT entity, COUNT(ll.logonID) AS MaxlogonIDs
FROM clients c 
    INNER JOIN LogOnsLink ll ON ll.clientID=c.clientID 
WHERE c.entity LIKE '%Com%' 
GROUP BY entity
ORDER BY entity
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT entity
FROM clients c 
    INNER JOIN LogOnsLink ll ON ll.clientID=c.clientID 
WHERE c.entity LIKE '%Com%' 
ORDER BY entity
```

Comment: The only problem with the DISTINCT here is that i need the ll.logonID. Also, what does MAX(ll.logonID) do?

Comment: @Damien `MAX()` takes the highest value per `entity` in the query above.

Comment: I'm having a problem still with using max. I had to change my SQL statement to add more info. Now it's not selecting unique values. Any ideas? Here's the revised SQL: SELECT MAX(contactID), entity, code, address FROM contacts WHERE entity LIKE '%Com%' GROUP BY entity,code,address ORDER BY entity

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT ll.logonID, DISTINCT(entity) 
FROM Clients c INNER JOIN LogOnsLink ll 
ON ll.clientID=c.clientID 
WHERE c.entity LIKE '%Com%' 
ORDER BY entity
```